# Estou tentando inserir dois valores de um objeto ao mesmo tempo dentro de uma tabela, preciso q o valor do mono[0] fosse inserido junto com linha[0]

Tags: javascript

```
const mono = () => {
        const mono = ['17.25', '18.11', '19.02', '19.97', '20.97', '22.02', '23.12', '24.27'];
        const linha = [46, 53, 60, 67, 74, 81, 88, 95];

        for(let i of mono){
            const valor = ('R$' + i);
            for(let y = 0; y < linha.length; y++){
                insereValorLinha(linha[y], valor);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Você não explicou qual o erro, ou onde seu código se comporta diferente do esperado (muito embora considerando o aninhamento de `for`, você deve estar recebendo uma combinação de todos os valores de cada uma das matrizes dois a dois).

Comment: isso mesmo, está acontecendo isso, mas estou querendo que o valor de mono[0] seja inserido junto com o valor de linha[0] e assim sucessivamente.